# Microsoft Graph only available in Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

May I ask about Microsoft Graph only work for Office 365?

How about Share Point 2013 on premise?

Because currently I developed an app that need to retrieve the data from SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Can't you use SharePoint REST API's?

Comment: After I deployed to bot services its shown the error.

Comment: MS Graph API mainly handles O365 cloud services and doesn't know about your local environment. you may find details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Graph supports the online resources only. Access on-premises data will require using the service-specific resources.

A helpful resource is the [SharePoint .NET Server, CSOM, JSOM, and REST API index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-net-server-csom-jsom-and-rest-api-index)